# android - Generate Image Views according to the value in a String variable

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout, listview

I am developing an application where I need to generate `ImageViews` according to the value saved in a String variable.

For instance, if `String strNoOfImages = 2`, then 2 image views should be generated inside a layout.

Please see the code below:

```
for (int i=0; i < resultArray.length; i++){

            String strElemnet = resultArray[i].toString();
            strNoOfImages = strElemnet.split(";")[2];  // NO OF IMAGES AT INDEX 2 OF ARRAY
            strHeadings = strElemnet.split(";")[1]; // HEADINGS AT INDEX 1 OF ARRAY

           if(strNoOfImages != null){
                 // is this a write method?
                 // if yes, what should i write here?

           }
}
```

'strNoOfImages' contains a value like 2,3 or any other number. I just want to generate Image Views according to the values in 'strNoOfImages'.

Also, I wanted to know if do I also have to create `imageView` in activity_mail.xml too?

Please respond for any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

You can set how many image you want to show in the GridView by changing the return value of **getCount()** method.

Comment: I cant use GridView, infact i want to load the images inside a 'HorizontalScrollView' Layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can add imageView at runtime for that take any layout in your xml and then add imageView in that layout at run time as per your conditions.

```
for (int i=0; i < resultArray.length; i++){

            String strElemnet = resultArray[i].toString();
            strNoOfImages = strElemnet.split(";")[2];  // NO OF IMAGES AT INDEX 2 OF ARRAY
            strHeadings = strElemnet.split(";")[1]; // HEADINGS AT INDEX 1 OF ARRAY

           if(strNoOfImages != null){
                    for(int images=0;images<=strNoOfImages;images++){
                      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10); //optional you can also set more margins 

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context); //context is the activity context say, this
    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView); // here linearlayout is the layout whichever you have add in your xml in which you are adding your imageView
}
                 // is this a write method?
                 // if yes, what should i write here?

           }
}
```

Using this you can add any numbers of Imageviews as per your conditions.

Comment: its giving an error at 'images<=strNoOfImages' , which states 'Operator '<=' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.lang.String

Comment: its beacause of you have taken return type of "strNoOfImages" is String that's why plz take it int

Comment: Or another solutions is that you can parse integer value from that string

Comment: Now the exception is 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference'

Comment: Should I create an adapter class and write this for loop in code in that, inside getView() function??